# Creating Serial Pressence Detect data from discrete DDR RAM datasheet

Tags: ram, ddr, ddr3

I have a board that has soldered discrete DDR RAM chips. The datasheet for the DDR RAM chips is available to me. The DDR memory controller is programmed manually using pre-calculated values.

I have modified the bootloader (u-boot) to perform automagic DDR memory controller initialization. u-boot will act as if the discrete memory is a DIMM. For this to work, the SPD chip read process was modifed. When u-boot performs a read of the SPD data an array containing the SDP data will accessed. All I need now is an array of valid SPD data that matches the configuration.

I have the DDR RAM chip datasheet, and I've got one day (or more) to spare. How do I create the SPD data? What are the maths involved? What free tools are available?

Comment: I suggest getting hold of appropriate DIMM datasheets for comparison, and trawling micron.com for app notes on DIMMs and SPD.

Comment: That's what I have been doing though on the samsung website. The installed chips are K4B4G1646D. Closest DIMM I've found is M471B5674QH0-YH9/K0 which uses K4B4G1646Q. Different die, and different speed bins. I found an SPD dump for the DIMM in the chromiumos project https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/coreboot/+/f0a1366d328f84e720fe7768cecfe57b3e7dca79/src/mainboard/google/falco/Samsung_M471B5674QH0.spd.hex though the generated settings for the DDR controller does not work! So I wanted to start from scratch (if needed).

Comment: I'd imagine you could learn a lot from the portion of the u-boot source which parses what it finds?

Comment: I've dowloaded a copy of the SPD spec from http://www.xdevs.com/article/ddr4s/ and am manually creating the SPD data. I think understanding the timings in the datasheet with its relation to the SPD data is paramount. Seems easy enough but the DDR is still not working correctly.